# Permission denied when cleaning directory for testing with help of 'rmdir' lib

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, rmdir

Using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rmdir)
rmdir library I successfully cleaning my directory before test in order to test my files downloading and to avoid already existed files to occur false passing.

```
exec('rm -r ' + path, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
            console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            console.log(' ERROR!!! -- Folder download was not cleaned up before test or it is wrong WARN');
            console.error(err)
            console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------------');
            }
```

But the problem is I have callback function and it catches this error:

```
ERROR!!! -- Folder download was not cleaned up before test or it is wrong WARN
{ Error: Command failed: rm -r /Users/myPath/Downloads
rm: /Users/alexandertunick/Downloads: Permission denied
```

it's nothing terrible but it might cause the false alarm when some error really occurred.

Comment: Are you sure it's a false alarm? That error message sounds like the directory wasn't deleted due to a permissions error.

Comment: @EdwinTorresD.Eng. Thaks for your response. Yeah, i'm pretty sure, before I added this lib to my tests I tested its functionality quite many times and I've seen how it greatly cleaning directory. I heard some point, that this command trying not only to clean up the directory but to delete it as well. Dunno is that right.

Comment: rm -r somedir will delete the directory somedir, along with its contents. If you want to remove the files in the directory, but not the directory itself, then... rm somedir/*

Comment: Thanks, I will try and comment the result here

Comment: @EdwinTorresD.Eng. Yeah, it helped. Thanks, the command initially wrongly explained in this Lib. Now I know the difference, this also helped https://askubuntu.com/questions/60228/how-to-remove-all-files-from-a-directory

Comment: I don't know only how to give you +1 for your help here

Comment: LOL. Just upvote my comment if you think it helped. ;-)

Comment: got it, but it's not sufficient number of my reputation to upvote, so perhaps it will return to this in future:)